# Can you monitor the progress of a neo4j constraint

Tags: neo4j, constraints

We have a neo4j database running 2.2 and I was wondering if anyone has a way on monitoring the progress of a constraint? The reason I ask is the docs say that constraints can take a while and I want to know when its done. I havent read anywhere in the docs that says you can do this and tailing the console.log and messages.log files do not show any progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `:schema` command in the browser. It will list all the constraints and indexes. Indexes marked as `ONLINE` are fully populated and Cypher will use them. Indexes in `POPULATING` status are still about to be created and not yet usable.

In Java API you can use `GraphDatabaseService.schema().getIndexState(IndexDefinition)`.

Comment: And you can use "schema await" for an index if you want to block until population is done.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Ill give that a shot and hopefully it can give me the information i need.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question on constraint creation progress!